# Firefox cache: Is it possible to retrieve the text or images of deleted facebook posts from files cached locally on my computer?

Tags: facebook, firefox, caching, browser, browser-cache

This is a fairly self explanatory question.

Recently I deleted a facebook note which contained some information about some ideas I had for a research project which I thought I had written down but hadn't.

Is it possible that a browser (I am using Firefox) caches that information locally on my machine? If so can I retrieve it somehow?

Also to extend and generalize this idea, would I be able to retrieve information such as recently deleted images?